# Difference between "Not welcome in our community" and Offensive

Tags: discussion, flagging

I just saw a post that blatantly asked for tips to script a DDoS attack.
Now a post like this is not Welcome to our community. We do not help script attacks, however, when flagging the post as such, it got marked as "Offensive".

That post wasn't Offending me in any way, I wanted to mark it as Not welcome in our community. Maybe the two could be separated? Or else, in which way should I be flagging such posts in the future?

Comment: In general, I see a flag as something that should grab my attention. The *reason* you give the flag is a helpful indicator, but it's not binding.

Comment: In my opinion, a technical forum should not make moral judgements like that. Does google refuse to index such information? Where do you draw the line? There are legitimate reasons to script attacks and run exploits, such as to test if your systems are vulnerable.  The best solution is to identify who is actually committing illegal attacks, and kick them off the internet (to jail, perhaps). Unless the content is in itself actually illegal to publish, I don't see why it should be prohibited here.

Comment: @SamWatkins Where do we draw the line? As defined in our legal policy: http://stackexchange.com/legal

Answer (score 3):

I think "Not welcome in our community" is a bit broad. Anything that is being flagged is really, "not welcome in our community." That's why it's being flagged. Plus, really it is offensive, as it is a question about an attack. An attack is surely offensive.

Comment: I don't think a DDoS attack is offensive, actually. It's not hate speech, it's not directly insulting someone, or anything else like that. It's damaging, yes, and it's an inconvenience for whoever has to deal with it, but that's not the same thing as being offensive.

Comment: It is offensive in the way that it is on the offense. The question in itself is not offensive, but the answer would be.